# Can I use rspec mocks to stub out version constants?

Tags: ruby, rspec, constants, mocking

I've got code that only needs to run on a certain version of ActiveRecord (a workaround for a bug on old AR libraries). This code tests the values of ActiveRecord::VERSION constants to see if it needs to be run.

Is there a way to mock out those constants in rspec so I can test that code path without relying on having the right ActiveRecord gem installed on the test machine?

Answer (score 11):

I ended up writing a helper method to let me override constants while executing a block of code:

```
def with_constants(constants, &block)
  constants.each do |constant, val|
    Object.const_set(constant, val)
  end

  block.call

  constants.each do |constant, val|
    Object.send(:remove_const, constant)
  end
end
```

After putting this code in your spec_helper.rb file, it can be used as follows:

```
with_constants :RAILS_ROOT => "bar", :RAILS_ENV => "test" do
  code goes here ...
end
```

Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 9):

With RSpec 2.11, constant stubbing is supported out of the box with `stub_const`:

```
describe "stub_const" do
  it "changes the constant value for the duration of the example" do
    stub_const("Foo::SIZE", 10)
    expect(Foo::SIZE).to eq(10)
  end
end
```

See Myron Marston's announcement for more details:

- https://rspec.info/blog/2012/06/constant-stubbing-in-rspec-2-11/

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, still valid 11 years past!

Answer (score 2):

Drew Olson, I took your idea and made a few modifications to add scoping:

```
class Object
  def self.with_constants(constants, &block)
    old_constants = Hash.new
    constants.each do |constant, val|
      old_constants[constant] = const_get(constant)
      silence_stderr{ const_set(constant, val) }
    end

    block.call

    old_constants.each do |constant, val|
      silence_stderr{ const_set(constant, val) }
    end
  end
end
```

After putting this code at specs/support/with_constants.rb file, it can be used as follows:

```
MyModel.with_constants :MAX_RESULT => 2, :MIN_RESULT => 1 do
  code goes here ...
end
```

Comment: Use ```Kernel::silence_warnings { const_set(constant, val) }```instead ```silence_stderr{ const_set(constant, val) }``` when you stub method before call your code.

Answer (score 1):

Add rescue block is important for ensure restore constant for another tests in test suite !

```
class Object
  class << self
    def with_constants(constants, &block)
      old_constants = Hash.new
      constants.each do |constant, val|
        old_constants[constant] = const_get(constant)
        Kernel::silence_warnings { const_set(constant, val) }
      end

      error = nil
      begin
        block.call
      rescue Exception => e
        error = e
      end

      old_constants.each do |constant, val|
        Kernel::silence_warnings { const_set(constant, val) }
      end

      raise error unless error.nil?
    end
  end
end
```

Typically

```
describe "#fail" do

  it "should throw error" do
    expect {
      MyModel.with_constants(:MAX_RESULT => 1) do
        # code with throw error
      end
    }.to raise_error
  end

end
```